# Coordinate geometry dividing the plane by pairwise straight line

Tags: plane-geometry

Three pairwise straight line intersecting (but not at the same point) by how many parts these lines divides the plane?

Comment: Have you tried drawing it and counting them?

Comment: I have limited knowledge about cordinate geometry..actually i don't understand the question fully..is 3 pairwise means 3 pair straight line with different slpoe or normal 6 straight line? I will be happly if somone help how to draw the figure

Comment: The word 'pairwise' is used for groups of more than 2 objects to say that any pair of the objects satisfy the relation. For example, a collection of integers is called 'coprime' if their greatest common divisor is 1; but they are called 'pairwise coprime' if every pair is coprime. 'Pairwise straight' doesn't make any sense, because being straight is a property of a single line, not a relation between multiple lines. I'm guessing you mean the lines are 'pairwise intersecting', so any pair of lines intersects. But as you say, not in one single common point.

Comment: So the picture is like a triangle, but you continue the edges to be lines (i.e., infinitely long lines) in both directions. Does this help you draw it?